# Need help with invisible content block

Tags: content

I am new to WordPress, I have created a page for latest news, using a content block 'content | blog', the content is there as it is still clickable, however, it is not showing up, it isn't visible to the user. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you ellaborate on what you mean by `content block`? Is this a widget? A GB block? A special area in your theme?

Comment: In addition to what @Tom J Nowell said, I'd add: What do you mean "fix it"? Do you want to remove the content completely? Do you want to make it visible?